# Visual Basic - SQL syntax error

Tags: vb.net

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key=''' at line 1"

And it points out the  data = command.ExecuteReader

Any ideas what the problem could be?

https://gyazo.com/c2ba211b42571555fa34564b308239d6

```
    Private Sub Button_Registre_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button_Registre.Click
    Dim conn As MySqlConnection
    conn = New MySqlConnection("server=sql7.com;userid=51384;password=FEfY;database=51384")
    Dim LicenseKey As Boolean = True
    conn.Open()
    Dim sqlquery As String = "SELECT * FROM license_keys WHERE key='" & TextBox_LicenseKey.Text & "'"
    Dim data As MySqlDataReader
    Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim command As New MySqlCommand
    command.CommandText = sqlquery
    command.Connection = conn
    adapter.SelectCommand = command
    data = command.ExecuteReader
    While data.Read()
        If data.HasRows() = True Then
            MsgBox("License key are wrong!")
            LicenseKey = False
            data.Close()
        Else
            data.Close()
            LicenseKey = True
        End If
    End While
    data.Close()
    If LicenseKey = True Then
        RegistreNewUser()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You really should not concatenate a value into a query string, use parameters! Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. As to the specific problem, you may need to use `\`key\`` instead of `key`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen key might be a reserved word, so it needs to be quoted (not 100% sure).

Comment: `key` is a MySQL reserved keyword.  You should escape it with backticks, but better yet don't call your columns `'key'`, since they aren't keys, they're columns.

Comment: Got it working thanks!

Comment: Dim sqlquery As String
sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM license_keys WHERE 'key'='" & TextBox_LicenseKey.Text & "'"

Comment: That code made it work!